# Ubuntu 22.04 usually not recognizing 4k monitor; treats it as 1024x768

Tags: 22.04, monitor

**Display**: Lenovo Qreator 27, connected via DP

**Machine**: Lenovo M75s; dual boot Windows and Ubuntu 22.04

**Problem**: Setup works perfectly in Windows, so I believe the hardware is OK. But most of the time Ubuntu doesn't recognize the monitor, and falls back on a 1024x768 resolution. Even if the login screen is at full resolution, logging in can fall back to the low-res default. Logging out and back in eventually wins the jackpot, and the monitor is properly recognized, but it can take a dozen attempts or more.

**Sub-problem**: Even when the monitor is recognized, the audio usually isn't. (But sometimes it is...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable proprietary drivers? You may need them. Open app "Additional Drivers."

[image: additional drivers]

I think your machine may have AMD GPU. The last time I used AMD GPU, there was a choice between "Pro" driver and regular driver. You could try both.

Also, are you on Wayland or X11? Could be worth a shot to switch: on login screen, when you start typing your password, click on settings icon on bottom right.

"Ubuntu" is wayland, and "Xorg" is X11.

Comment: No additional drivers available :-(

Comment: Have tried switching between Ubuntu (Wayland) and Xorg. No difference in behavior.